# How to troubleshoot multicasting on mac?

Tags: macos, multicast, oracle-coherence

I have just started using oracle-coherence. I am facing issues in setting up that. After googling, I got to know that to use oracle-coherence multicast needs to be enabled.

I tested if the multicast is enabled on my system or not.

```
multicast-test.sh -ttl 0
```

Results of this command:

```
Sent packet 1 containing 1468 bytes.
Sent packet 2 containing 1468 bytes.
Sent packet 3 containing 1468 bytes.
Sent packet 4 containing 1468 bytes.
Sent packet 5 containing 1468 bytes.
Sent packet 6 containing 1468 bytes.
Sent packet 7 containing 1468 bytes.
Sent packet 8 containing 1468 bytes.
Sent packet 9 containing 1468 bytes.
```

That simply means my system is just sending but not receiving these bytes. How to proceed now?

**What I tried**

```
ifconfig
```

shows `UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST` for en0

```
netstat -nr
```

shows routing tables. Earlier, there was no entry of 228.0.0.X . I added 228.0.0.4 in routing table.

But even now the multicast test is showing the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try including system property -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true when launching the JVM.